# Expo web development ENV build

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

What is the best way to build an Expo web app development build?

1. Does `expo build:web -d` build a web app with
   `__DEV__` set to true within the built/deployed app?

I have tried this method but I am still seeing DEV as false.

If this is the expected behavior, what does the -d flag do when building expo for web?

2. Using dotenv, how can I create development vs. production builds using `expo build:web`?
   https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv
3. How can app.json / app.config.js extra fields be used to set up staging env?
   https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#extra
   Is use of `__DEV__` necessary?

Comment: Implemented a development staging build by following comments here:
https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/948

```
// app.config.js
export default {
  expo: {
    apiUrl: process.env.STAGING_BUILD === 'development' ? 'DEV_API_URL' : 'API_URL'
  }
}
```

```
// build script
BUILD_STAGING=development expo build:web
```

Comment: should we close this question then?

Comment: Sure, what action should I take to close the question?

Comment: I think the best thing to do is to put your comment as an answer and mark it as the correct answer. I think you even get points for solving your own problem! Congrats!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented a development staging build by following comments here by passing a `BUILD_STAGING` key when executing the build script and checking for the key value in `app.config.js`:

github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/948

```
// app.config.js
export default {
  expo: {
    apiUrl: process.env.STAGING_BUILD === 'development' ? 'DEV_API_URL' : 'API_URL',
  },
};
```

```
// build script
BUILD_STAGING=development expo build:web
```